# Groovy closures, def vs typed return value

Tags: groovy, closures

In the Groovy console, version 2.2.1:
Why does this work?

```
class C {
  def foo = { "foo" }
  def bar = { foo() }
}
new C().bar()
```

but this fails?

```
class C {
  String foo = { "foo" }
  String bar = { foo() }
}    
new C().bar()
```

The above was answered by tim_yates but I have something somewhat related that doesn't seem like it's worth creating a new question for (not sure of the etiquette). When I make them static it also fails when I call bar(). Why does the bar closure not capture foo?

```
class C {
  static foo = { "foo" }
  static bar = { foo() }
}    
C.foo() //works
C.bar() //fails
```

Comment: I think that should be a different question

Comment: Thanks, tim_yates. I posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814923/groovy-closure-not-capturing-static-closure-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because neither `{ "foo" }` or `{ foo() }` are Strings?

They are `Closure<String>`

Try:

```
class C {
  Closure<String> foo = { "foo" }
  Closure<String> bar = { foo() }
}    
new C().bar()
```