# Groovy closure not capturing static closure variable

Tags: groovy, closures

Can someone please explain why the call to **qux** fails? It doesn't seem to capture the name of the static closure variable **foo** when it is created. If I purposely assign the name to a variable as in **baz** it works, or if I call it through the class. I thought this variable capture should work for closure class variables too but I must be missing something.

```
class C {
  static foo = { "foo" }
  static bar = { C.foo() }
  static baz = { def f = foo; f() }
  static qux = { foo() }
}    
println C.foo() //works
println C.bar() //works
println C.baz() //works
println C.qux() //fails
```

I also tried this as a test and it had no problem capturing the **i** variable:

```
class C {
  static i = 3
  static times3 = { "foo: ${it * i}" }
}    
println C.times3(2) //works
```

[edit] 
Lastly, if **foo** is simply a method, it also works as I expected:

```
class C {
  static foo() { "foo" }
  static bar = { foo() }
}    
println C.bar() //works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3422). If you treat `foo` as an attribute, it works:

```
class C {
  static foo = { "foo" }
  static bar = { C.foo() }
  static baz = { def f = foo; f() }
  static qux = { foo.call() }
}    
assert C.foo() == 'foo'
assert C.bar() == 'foo'
assert C.baz() == 'foo'
assert C.qux() == 'foo'
```

Comment: Good find there in the bug database! I agree it sounds like exactly that issue. Looks like it's been around for a while too.

Comment: Scheduled to be fixed in groovy 3. With traits and new MOP, i think v3 will rock.